# How do I resize the main partition of my newly created ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I am new to ubuntu server and still pretty mystified by all the scripts and such.  I have been reading different things available on the web and have successfully created my server and have several folders that I am able to write to using my windows computers.  The problem is, when I was following one of the tutorials to start, I created a partition of 20gb to use for the OS.  I have a 2tb disk and now I am out of space, even though I have another 1.8tb available.  I used the lvm option when I loaded the system and was lead to believe I could expand the partition easily.  The problem is, I don't know how and I can't seem to find an example that seems to fit my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using ubuntu server 14.04

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lvm then resize2fs will be the last step. Op, please share your 'fdisk -l' output. If you have graphical tools installed then gparted will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Find where your root

Enter "resize2fs /dev/root" to use all available space or "resize2fs /dev/root [sizeToExpandTo] to specify what to change it to that should do the trick.

Take a look at the resize2fs man page for more info.